# Across vs athwart

Tags: differences, prepositions

**[athwart](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/athwart)** PREPOSITION

> From side to side of; across.
>
> - ‘a counter was placed **athwart** the entrance’.

Isn't it grammatical if I say across rather than athwart, as in:

> - ‘a counter was placed **across** the entrance’.

**Please make me understand, if I am asking wrong.**

In the following [link](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-76iKHyk-FZ8/Uzc4yal6qDI/AAAAAAAAXIA/k0V5CcDIpIo/s1600/10151258_673381019393603_2141350916_n.jpg), there is a visual preposition concept figure.

Comment: Mainly, if you're in the water then you use "athwart".

Comment: Anyone please, edit and upload the picture of a link given above. I am using unsupported web browser.

Comment: @HotLicks, can you please provide an example of athwart being in water?

Comment: "Athwart" is a nautical term.

Comment: In reading or in in writing? 'athwart' is an incredibly rare and archaic term (never used conversationally), has been in decline since 1900, and is used <1% compared to 'across'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**athwart** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/12512?redirectedFrom=athwart#eid) Yes, your use is grammatical:

> 3. Across the course (of anything), so as to thwart or oppose progress.

There are 4 other senses, on of them being nautical.

Answer (score 3):

Usage note on ***[athwart:](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/athwart)***

> ***Use the adverb athwart to describe something that reaches or stretches across, or from one side to another***. You might hang a "Happy Birthday" banner athwart your office doorway to celebrate your coworker's birthday.
>
> You can describe things that stretch sideways or span between objects as athwart, and ***you can also use the word to mean "in opposition to" or "against."*** For example, you might say that your plans to paint the house dark gray run athwart your roommate's plan, which involves hot pink with gold trim.
>
> In the fifteenth century, the word was coined by adding a to the word thwart, which comes from the Old Norse root word þvert, or "across."

(Vocabulary.com)

Comment: how do you distinguish between athwart and across? I think OP needs to know it.